# Categories and hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm having trouble in my hashmap. I've got two hashmaps. One `hashmap<String,Integer>` with products from a restaurant with initial values = 0 , and the  second one`hashmap<String,String>`  with all categories like(meals, beverages, desserts, etc).

I can write to the file and do almost everything that is asked less write an unknown product category. How can I do that?

```
HashMap<String, Integer> prod = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    prod.put("Bacalhau à Zé do Pipo", 0);
    prod.put("Bitoque", 0);
    prod.put("Salada de atum", 0);

    prod.put("Café", 0);
    prod.put("Coca-cola(lata)", 0);
    prod.put("7Up(lata)", 0);

    prod.put("Bolo de bolacha", 0);
    prod.put("Banana", 0);
    prod.put("Melão", 0);

    prod.put("Pau de canela", 0);
    prod.put("Bagaço", 0);
    prod.put("Pastilhas Gorila", 0);

Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();       
    map.put("Bacalhau à Zé do Pipo", "meals");
    map.put("Bitoque", "meals");
    map.put("Salada de atum", "meals");

    map.put("Café", "beverages");
    map.put("Coca-cola(lata)", "beverages");
    map.put("7Up(lata)", "beverages");

    map.put("Bolo de bolacha", "desserts");
    map.put("Banana", "desserts");
    map.put("Melão", "desserts");

    map.put("Pau de canela", "Other");
    map.put("Bagaço", "Other");
    map.put("Pastilhas Gorila", "Other");´
```

Comment: Can you give more details on what exactly you are trying to do, what you have tried, and why it isn't working?

Comment: Do you want to write out all the product categories saved in the HashMap to the file?

Comment: Java is an OOP language, so these 'products from a restaurant' would be best represented as an Object. Namely, `Item(String name, String category, double price)`. Or you could go on to have a category [enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).

Comment: posting a little bit of code might help here

Comment: What do you mean by "write an unknown product category"?

Comment: I'm sorry i didn't specified. My code reads from a input.txt file, and store the integer on hashmap. the products are on this input.txt file. I need to create a category for files that don't exist on `HashMap<String, Integer> prod = new HashMap<String, Integer>();`